# Using MSPf5529 with UART returns spacing cedilla in Mac

Tags: msp430

I'm trying to use the MSPF5529 with my mac. I've downloaded code composer studio and can easily access the chip as well as blink lights and any other application I need.

The goal is for me to print a message using UART through serial communication on my Mac.  I am currently using an application called "goSerial" in order to communicate with the chip.  My code below initializes UART, takes in a single character, and then it is supposed to print out a character, and then blink a light.  However, instead, the code takes in the character, and prints out a strange symbol, called a spacing cedilla, with a hex value of 0xFC, and then blinks the light.

This symbol appears regardless of which character I put into the MSP430 buffer.

My code is listed below. Has anyone had this problem before? How do I solve this?

```
 void Init_UART(void);
 void OUTA_UART(unsigned char A);
 unsigned char INCHAR_UART(void);
 #include "msp430f5529.h"
 #include "stdio.h"


 int main(void){
 volatile unsigned char a;
 volatile unsigned int i;
 WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;
 Init_UART();
 a=INCHAR_UART();

 a=INCHAR_UART();
 OUTA_UART(a);
 // go blink the light to indicate code is running
 P1DIR |= 0x01;
 for (;;){
 P1OUT ^= 0x01; i = 10000;
 do i--;
 while (i != 0); }

 }




 void OUTA_UART(unsigned char A){ 
 while ((UCA1STAT&UCBUSY));
 // send the data to the transmit buffer
 UCA1TXBUF =A;
 }



 unsigned char INCHAR_UART(void){ 
 while ((UCA1STAT&UCBUSY) == 0);
 // go get the char from the receive buffer
 return (UCA1RXBUF);
 }

 void Init_UART(void){
     P4SEL |= 0x30;     // Port 4.4 and port 4.5 controls the transfer 
     UCA1CTL1|= UCSWRST;  // Put state machine in reset
     UCA1CTL1|= UCSSEL_1;       //Choose 32765Hz
     UCA0BR0=3;             // Baud rate = 9600
     UCA0BR1=0;             // Choose 32765 hz
     UCA1MCTL=0x06;         // Modulation UCBRSx=3, UCBFx = 0
     UCA1CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;      // Put USCI in operation mode

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UCBUSY flag is not very useful, and cannot be used like this.

That a byte has been received is indicated by UCRXIFG:

```c
while (!(UCA1IFG & UCRXIFG)) ;
return UCA1RXBUF;
```

That a byte can be sent is indicated by UCTXIFG:

```c
while (!(UCA1IFG & UCTXIFG)) ;
UCA1TXBUF = a;
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, my code still doesn't print anything useful out. I don't understand why it isn't working.
For some reason it keeps printing this string:

·í···Ä˛Ì

Comment: Probably a wrong baud rate; the clock is not very accurate without a crystal.

Comment: You were right, my baud rate was wrong. Once I fixed it, it solved the problem. Thanks for the help!  Unfortunately my reputation is so bad on here that I cannot up vote you but believe me, I would if I could :)